# Безопасность в REST сервисе на JAX-RS

Tags: java, безопасность, rest, jboss, jax-rs

Пишу REST сервис на JAX-RS (если быть точным, RESTeasy от JBoss). Сразу говорю, что плохо разбираюсь в вопросах безопасности и с вебом знаком тоже не очень, поэтому и возникла такая проблема. И, честно говоря, я не знаю, что искать.

Вопросов куча, и я буду весьма благодарен, если вы поделитесь своими знаниями на этот счёт, или подскажете, где искать такую информацию и какую терминологию использовать. Также, был бы очень рад, если кто-нибудь посоветовал статьи/книги по безопасности в веб.

**Каким образом можно реализовать авторизацию клиента в сервисе и дальнейшую проверку наличия доступа к закрытым частям сервиса?**

То есть, предположим, у меня реализован простой POST запрос через HTTPS, в котором передаётся логин и пароль пользователя. И если данные верны, то как в дальнейшем проверять наличие доступа у данного клиента и идентифицировать его от других? Неужели в каждый запрос вкладывать логин и пароль? Какие методы аутентификации используются для REST сервисов?

И как при этом сохранить "красоту" кода: отделить логику-безопасности, от бизнес-логики?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/245415/ : Basic Authentication, Digest authentication, Token Authentication, Digital Signature (public/private key pair), Certificate Authentication, OAuth2 authorization - ищем в контексте RESTeasy вместо SPRING.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря DimXenon нашёл [этот хороший отве](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777083/best-practice-for-rest-token-based-authentication-with-jax-rs-and-jersey)т на мой вопрос на англоязычном StackOverflow. Всё просто и понятно, с удобным разделением логики безопасности и бизнесс логики. Если кто-то переведёт и представит в виде ответа на изначальный вопрос, будет замечательно.